# Proof of cantor's theorem.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, infinity

**Claim**: $P(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is uncountable.
*Proof*.
Suppose its not; then we can let $X_1,X_2,...$ be an enumeration of $P(\mathbb{Z}^+)$. Let $g:P(\mathbb{Z}^+)\setminus\{\mathbb{Z}^+\}\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ be a function that maps each proper subset $X\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$ to some $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x\notin X$. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}\{g(X_i)\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^+$, so $\bigcup_{i=1}\{g(X_i)\}=X_j$ for some $j$. But then $g(X_j)\in\bigcup_{i=1}\{g(X_i)\}$, so $g(X_j)\in X_j$; but by def of $g$, $g(X_j)\notin X_j$; contradiction. Therefore $P(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ is countable.

Is it valid? Someone told me my method of using $g$ is not the best, but they didn't tell if the proof is valid.

Comment: Your proof is valid but your definition of $g$ needs (some weak form of) the axiom of choice. You can get rid of that by taking "the smallest $x$" instead of "some $x$".

Comment: Maybe I am thick but ... how does it follow that $g(X_j)\in\bigcup\{g(X_i)\}$?

Comment: If $X_j = \mathbb Z^+\backslash \{n\}$ then $g(X_j)$ necessarily equals $n$, and thus $\{g(X_j): j \in \mathbb Z^+\}=\mathbb Z^+$, which is also what the argument that $G\neq X_j$ for any $j$ says, so I'm not sure this works. Am I missing something though?

Comment: @krm2233 yeah its not valid. The union $\bigcup_{i=1}\{g(X_i)\}$ contains $\bigcup_{i=1}\{g(\{\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus\{i\}\})\}=\bigcup_{i=1}\{i\}=\mathbb{Z}^+$